# Can you redirect lights/lasers to arbitrary points without moving parts?

Tags: optics

Specifically I was wondering about Laser on Phosphor displays, as they are similar to CRTs I was curious if you could make it even more similar (and last longer) by replacing the mirrors with something not motorized. As you can't use magnetic fields like a CRT I wondered if there was something else you could use to redirect/refract light that would change properties when exposed to electricity or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is perfectly possible.

The simplest example is a [spatial light modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator), which uses a bunch of liquid-crystal pixels to alter the phase and amplitude of the light at a given plane; using some additional focusing optics, this can be used to produce arbitrary spot shapes and placements in a given image plane. (Basically, the re-imaging produces a Fourier transform, so you want your SLM to have the Fourier transform of the spot you want to image.)

Other mechanisms are certainly possible, but it's not within this site's format to provide extensive lists of that kind.

Comment: An Acousto-Optic light deflector [http://www.optoscience.com/maker/gooch/pdf/IntroductionAO.pdf] is often used for that purpose. It uses high-intensity sound waves to induce a diffraction grating in a crystal.  Pitch of the grating is determined by the sound frequency, and in turn pitch determines angle of deflection of a light beam diffracted by the crystal.   An A-O deflector is very fast (millions of degrees per second) but has a small range of deflection angles (a few degrees).

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a perfectly reasonable option. The same should be true with electro-optic modulators, which use microwave fields for the same purpose.